# AWS : Workflow for deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, aws

I am using my company computer since I don't have another one or linux. Therefore, I am starting to use cloud resources to perform some tasks.

I have a very simple question: Since most cloud resources don't have a GUI, how can I perform simple checks e.g. visualizing the bounding boxes my algorithm has found on a picture?

How do people performing such tasks usually accomplish this? Is there an easy fix or do I have to go through the installation of GUI on the cloud instance? Or, do you usually just download the results locally and view them locally?

Comment: carve out quality time to teach yourself how to install linux on your laptop ... borrow or buy a cheap $75 laptop and install Ubuntu as the single OS on box ... no dual boot as its easier  ... and yes you will love linux ... welcome to the real world ... PS download the .ISO file for Ubuntu 19.04 then burn that ISO onto a usb stick and boot toy laptop with that usb plugged in ( I say toy as the laptop contains zero valuable data or files as this will reformat drive ) ... installing Ubuntu takes minutes from zero to hero

Comment: Sorry but your answer is completely out of scope. The main point of using aws is primarily the GPU capacities, not linux.

Comment: another approach is to install sshfs on your local box and use it to share a directory living up on your aws instance ... so you can point your local box GUI analysis application at your mirrored local box dir which is getting shared with live file changes from the remote aws dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Simple suggestion is to install [python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux-python.html) , [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) on the Linux machine from command line. 
As Jupyter Notebook gets installed with Anaconda package.
Just give command 
`jupyter notebook` 
Now we can connect to ipython notebook in the Virtual Machine from the token generated from above command from any browser in any other machine locally.

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thanks !